# Using @ElementCollection and @CollectionTable on @MappedSuperclass base class with EclipseLink

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have a base class defined as follow:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseUser {
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_tags",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName= "tagName")})
    public Set<String> getTags() {...}
```

And a bunch of derived user classes which extends BaseUser.
With Hibernate a single "user_tags" table was created for all the derived classes (which was what I wanted).
After moving to EclipseLink it seems the engine tried to add the "owner_id" and the "tagName" columns over and over as the number of the derived classes which obviously result with table creation failure. 
Is there a way to get the same behavior as Hibernate in EclipseLink?
What does the JPA spec expects in such a scenario?

Comment: Since you marked @James's answer as correct, did you file a bug report? If yes, please add the reference to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug.  Please log the bug and vote for it.

It may have been fixed already, so please also try the latest version.